# "Чвиря" - українське слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, діалектизми

Зустрів в інтернеті [список](https://fakty.com.ua/ua/ukraine/20181109-10-ukrayinskyh-sliv-yaki-zbagatyat-vashu-movu/) 10-ти українських слів, які збагатять наше мовлення. Слово "чвиря" у ньому означає непогоду, слякоть: “А зима зовсім згнила, і шкульгає Різдво в мряку чвирі…” (Микола Хвильовий).

Але цього слова немає у [тлумачному словнику](http://sum.in.ua/), хоч всі інші слова зі списку там є. Проте в інших онлайн словниках, наприклад, [тут](https://ukrainian_russian.academic.ru/140880/%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F), можна зустріти це слово, а у прикладі, що я навів дається визначення "негода" і пише, що воно взято з тлумачного словника (але, як я вже написав, даного визначення там немає).

Отож чи таки можна вживати це слово у творах для ЗНО, щоб показати свої знання української мови, і чому його немає у [цьому популярному онлайн словнику](http://sum.in.ua/)? Бо я не впевнений, що джерела, у яких я знайшов визначення цього слова можна вважати надійними.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тому списку, на який ви посилаєтесь є таке тлумачення:

> Чвиря – негода, сльота.

Словник Грінченка (1907-1909):

> [Чвиря](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F), рі, ж. Ненастье. До сього часу, спасибі Богові, у городі сухо, бо не було ще чвирі. О. 1862. X. 117.

Як бачите словник 1909 року.

У словнику 1959 року слово "чвиря" має мітку "розмовне":

> [Російсько-український словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)
>   Ненастье
>
> - Будет, наступает, собирается ненастье – на негоду (на сльоту, іноді *розм.* на **чвирю**) береться (кладеться, йдеться); занегоджується.
> - Наступило ненастье – настала негода (іноді *розм.* **чвиря**); пішли негоди; занегодилося; засльотилося (іноді розм. зниж. зачвирилося); сльоти взялися.

Словник [2008 року](https://ukrainian_russian.academic.ru/140880/%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F) із міткою "діалектне":

> **чвиря** -і; *диал.*
>   нена́стье, непого́да, плоха́я пого́да
>   Українсько-російський словник. - ВТФ «Перун». В’ячеслав Бусел. 2008.

Схоже що значення "негода" правильне, його можна використовувати для збагачення мови, але для ЗНО я б його не використовував.

Answer (score 5):

### Надійні джерела

[Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on):

> надво́рі непого́диться (сльоти́ться), надво́рі **чви́ря** (пого́да)
> б’є.
>
> него́да, непого́да, не́погі[о]дь, не́гі[о]дь (-годи), него́диця,
> (слякоть) сльота́ и (мн.) сльо́ти (р. сльот), (зап.) слота́, сло́ти,
> (диал.) слякота́, плю́та, **чви́ря**, пого́да, ум. него́дка, него́донька.
>
> не(по)го́да була́, **чви́ря** би́ла.

[Етимолоґічний словник української мови (том 6):](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom6.pdf#page=275)

> [**чвир** (друге значення)] <<заметіль, хуртовина•> Нед, Пі, [
> **чвuра**, чвирк] «ТС.>> Нед, [ чвuря] <<**Негода, сльота**•>; - не зовсім ясне; мо­жливо, пов'язане із звуконаслідувальним чв:Іркати
> (див.).

[Корпус української мови](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx?l1=209):

> "А постать її прибила **чвиря**."
>
> "Знаєте - **чвиря** на глухім шляху."
>
> "Зима в п'ятім році нової ери була хора, бо довго не було снігу, а
> була  **чвиря**."

Цитати з творів Хвильового "Лілюлі" та "На глухім шляху".

[Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=12&highlight=on):

> **Чви́ря**, -рі, ж. Ненастье. До сього часу, спасибі Богові, у городі сухо, бо не було ще **чвирі**. О. 1862. X. 117.

### Менш надійні, але не менш помічні джерела

[Сайт горох:](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F)

> **ЧВИ́РЯ** Негода.
> Приклади:
>
> Ішла жура осінньої **чвирі**. Над міськими болотами шкульгали дощі – холодні й нудні. (М. Хвильовий)
>
> Образно. Риплять тачанки дощів і тріскотять кулемети **чвирі**. (М. Хвильовий)

### Обережний висновок

Хоч ми й бачимо, що це слово у літературі вживав переважно Хвильовий (а ще якийсь або якась невідомий/а "О" зі словника Грінченка), маємо достатньо посилань на авторитетні джерела з зазначенням цього слова. Вважаю, що можна вживати у ЗНО.

### Відступ

Забування радянськими лінґвістами, що складали СУМ-11, окремих слів української мови, небажання або неможливість вказати їх у тлумачному словнику навіть як "застарілі" - окрема тема для окремих запитань і обговорення. Маємо також почекати, коли у [СУМ-20](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/expls/) з'явиться літера Ч, і подивимось, чи там знову з'явиться це слово, а чи доведеться шукати наступного тлумачного словника.

Comment: У словнику Грінченка: «О. = Основа, южнорусскій литературно-ученый вѣстникъ. Спб. 1861—1862». 1862 — імовірно, рік видання, а X — можливо, місяць. Але як розшифрувати 117 — не знаю, бо нумерація сторінок, здається, не наскрізна ([1](http://escriptorium.univer.kharkov.ua/handle/1237075002/8375), [2](https://archive.org/details/osnova_1862_10-2/mode/2up)).

Answer (score 2):

Малорусько-німецький словник Євгена Желехівського та Софрона Недільського (1886):

> **Чвир, чвирк**, *m*. **чвира** , *f* .
>
> 1. Schneegestöber [хуртовина], n. (З*акревский Николай : Старосвѣтскій Бандуриста. Словарь малороссийскихъ идіомовъ, составилъ Ник. Закревскій, М. 1861*);
> 2. Fusel, Bodensatz nach der Destillation des Brantweins [сивуха, осад після перегонки самогону], *m. (Олекса Стороженко. I. 237. Котляревский И. П., 1875, с.5)*;
> 3. Trunkenheit, f. trunkener Muth [хміль, п'яна відвага], *(Закревский...)*;
> 4. s. Баґа, [недокурений тютюн в люльці] (*Піскунов Ф. „Словникъ живоі народнеі, пісьменноі і актовоі мови руських югівщанъ Россійской и Австрійско-Венґерскоі цесарії “, изд. 2. К. 1882).*

[Старосвѣтскій Бандуриста. Словарь малороссийскихъ идіомовъ, составилъ Ник. Закревскій (1861)](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/ukr0010870)

> **Чвира, Чвиркъ, Чвиръ, Шквиря, Хляга, Фуга, Хвуга,** П. Skwara, Skwar. 1) мятель, вьюга, 2) остатокъ послѣ перегонки спирта, 3) остатокъ хмѣля въ головѣ, [Я*къ же Чмыра злая чвира застукала въ полѣ*.] (*Грам. Павловского*)
>
> **Чмырь**. П. Czmyr, Szmer, Czmer, Czmyra, хмѣль въ головѣ; пьяное состояніе, Опьяненіе [Ишовь зъ корчмы Вакула Чмырь] т. е. горькій пяница. (*Грам. Павловского*)
>
> **Шквиря**, **Чвара**. **Хляха**, **Фуга**, П. Skwara, Skwar. жара, вьюга, непогода, дурная осенняя и зимняя погода.

Answer (score 1):

"Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови", Київ, 2001 (див. [«Україніка»](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/E_LIB/PDF/ukr0000728_14.pdf#page=5), [«ABBYY Lingvo Live»](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F) чи [«Словопедія»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53415/1016347.html)) містить "чвиря" як діалектизм:

> **чви́ря**, -і, *ж[іночий рід]*, *діал[ектне слово]*. Негода.